# modernizr not implementing svg fallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

im using modernizrs svgasimg to detect img tags with an svg source and replace the source to png if the browser doesnt support svg. I have downloaded and loaded the modernizr snippet for svgasimg and placed it before the following javascript:

```
if (Modernizr.svgasimg) {

} else {
 $(".logo").attr("src","images/logo3.png");

}
```

In ie8 the PNG is not being rendered as a fallback. Not sure what im doing wrong here?

Comment: is the path to `images/logo3.png` correct - could you make some `console.log('no svgasimg')` call in line after `$(".logo").attr("src","images/logo3.png");` ?

Comment: asking 'cause I can't imagine `Modernizr.svgasimg` false positive in IE8...

Comment: Yes so the first thing I did was console log a message and ie 8 gave the same message as in latest chrome